# How to set the color of a plotly line based on a number

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.cumsum( np.sqrt(1 / 1000) * np.random.normal(size=(1000, 10)), axis=0),
    columns=np.array([*range(1, 11)]))
```

and I want to plot it using plotly express and have the color of each plot to be based on the curves column value and I want the color to continuously evolve. So for example plots 1-3 ish could be yellow, then 4-7 could be orange and 8-10 could be red.

I tried

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, colors=df.columns)
fig.show()
```

but I received the error

```
All arguments should have the same length. The length of the argument 'color' is 10 where as the length of the previously-processed arguments ['index', '1', '2', '3', '4',..., '10'] is 1000
```

Essentially what I want to do is translate the following matplot lib code into plotly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc

cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis', df.shape[1])
norm = mplc.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=10)
for i, l in enumerate(df.T.values):
    plt.plot(l, color=cmap(norm(i)))
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(sm, label='signal number')
plt.show()
```

which returns the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I needed. I updated the graph to lines to illustrate that this code will not repeat colors.

```
  import plotly.graph_objects as go
  import plotly.express as px
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import matplotlib.colors as mplc
  import numpy as np

  no_sigs = 100

  line = lambda x, b: x + b
  lines = np.array(
          [line(time, b) for b in np.linspace(0, 1, 100)]
          )
  line_names = np.array([*range(1, no_sigs + 1)])
  lines_df = pd.DataFrame(
          data=lines.T,
          index=time,
          columns=line_names)

  # rgba colors and plot
  cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis', no_sigs)
  norm = mplc.Normalize(vmin=sig_names[0], vmax=sig_names[-1])

  # Initialize the color bar
  c_bar_data = np.vstack([lines_df.columns.values,
                          np.empty((2, int(no_sigs)))]).T
  colorbar_df = pd.DataFrame(
          data=c_bar_data,
          columns=['sig_num', 'empt1', 'empt2'])
  fig = px.scatter(colorbar_df,
                   x='empt1',
                   y='empt2',
                   color='sig_num',
                   color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)

  # Plot the lines
  for c in lines_df.columns:
      _ = fig.add_trace(
              go.Scatter(
                  y=lines_df[c].values,
                  line={'color': f'rgba{cmap(norm(c))}'},
                  showlegend=False)
              )
  _ = fig.update_xaxes(
          title={'text': 'x-axis'})
  _ = fig.update_yaxes(
          title={'text': 'y-axis'})
  fig.show()
```

Here is the output:[image]

Answer (score 1):

This reproduces your plot from `matplotlib` in `plotly.express`:

```py
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y=df.columns, color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Viridis)
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. I need to be able to specify a min and max color number values like I did in the matplotlib example, in particular the line `norm = mplc.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=10)`. In your example if I were too plot, say, 200 curves, then the plotly color palette just cycles through the colors and will repeat when it runs out of colors. But in the matplotlib example, the colors will continuously get brighter as the curve number increases and the color sequence wont repeat.